# How to get and hide siblings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, siblings

```
<ul>
    <li><a>home</li>
    <li><a onclick="erm()">about</li>
    <li><a>contact</li>
</ul>

<div id="all">
    <div id="home">Home</div>
    <div id="about">About</div>
    <div id="contact">Contact</div>
</div>
```

The divs from #all will initially be hidden.

How would I show just the contents of the #about div if the user will click on the 'about link' and hide the siblings in the same time?

I will basically use the same function on the same event for the other links.

Even a pseudo code might help, I can't get my head around it.

no jQuery please, but **vanilla Javascript**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution :

```
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
     var children = document.getElementById(parentId).children;
     for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) children[i].style.display="none";
     document.getElementById(toRevealId).style.display="block";
}
hideAllChildrenButOne('all', 'about');
```

Comment: +1, but just curious why you used `.childNodes` instead of `.children`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain That was an error (that I fixed just before I saw your comment)

Comment: fantastic, so simple/beautiful; thanks! will accept a bit later as it's too early now